# Merging multiple print areas dynamically to save to pdf in Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

Merging several print areas on an Excel sheet dynamically   All works perfect except for the union lines for print areas 11 to 14.  If I comment them out, everything else works.   Is there an issue with having the if statements between the code to set print areas Page_one and 11-14?

The error I get is Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

```
Sub SavetoPDF()

    Dim UseName As Variant
    Dim printRanges As Range

    UseName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:="Analytics for Labs.pdf", _
        FileFilter:="PDF files, *.pdf", _
        Title:="Export to pdf")

    If UseName <> False Then

       Set printRanges = Range("Cover_Page")

        With Application.WorksheetFunction

           Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Page_one"))

           If .CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Range("b31")) = 0 Then Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Page_three"))
           If .CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Range("j31")) = 0 Then Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Page_four"))
           If .CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Range("b55")) = 0 Then Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Page_five"))
           If .CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Range("j55")) = 0 Then Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Page_six"))
           If .CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Range("b78")) = 0 Then Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Page_seven"))
           If .CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Range("j78")) = 0 Then Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Page_eight"))
           If .CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Range("b86")) = 0 Then Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Page_nine"))
           If .CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Range("j86")) = 0 Then Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Page_ten"))

           Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Print_eleven"))
           Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Print_twelve"))
           Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Print_thirteen"))
           Set printRanges = Union(printRanges, Range("Print_fourteen"))

        End With

        printRanges.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=UseName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Verify that those ranges are valid. Can you check their values?

Comment: Solved:  I just deleted and redid the range definitions -- didn't change them, but it worked.  Essentially a hard re-boot.